# How to call a html <div> from <a href> link on the same html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a text and when I click the text, it will call the .
My code is as follow.

```
<h5>Posted On: {{postedDate | date}} <a href="" style="float:right" >Table Plans</a></h5>
```

When I click `Table Plans`, it should call the `div with id "tableImagesSliding"`.

```
<div id="tableImagesSliding" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="inner-box">
        <div class="mask-menu">
            <ul class="images ">
                <li class="display-inline" ng-repeat="tableImage in allTableImages">
                    <a href="" ng-click="showTableImage(tableImage.url)"><img ng-src="{{tableImage.url}}" width="600" height="400" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="triggers-menu slider-btn">
            <li ng-repeat="cnt in tablemapcount"></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag to point to an element on the page with an `id` by using the hash symbol.

```
<a href="#tableImagesSliding">Jump to table plans</a>

<div id="tableImagesSliding">
  Table plans div
</div>
```

For more information on valid uses of `href`, you can read the MDN page about [`a#href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) and about the [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id)

---

However, It's a bit more involved when using Angular...

Angular's router will get involved, and if it doesn't recognise the route, will (probably - depending on your setup) redirect to the main route.

You can use the [`$anchorScroll` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to get Angular to jump to the div for you.

Your HTML now contains an `ng-click`, and the controller uses `$anchorScroll`:

```js
angular.module('so42186303', [])
  .controller('so42186303Ctrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
     $scope.showTablePlans = function() {
       $location.hash('tableImagesSliding');
       $anchorScroll();
     };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="so42186303">
  <div ng-controller="so42186303Ctrl">
    <a ng-click="showTablePlans()">Click to jump to table plans</a>
    
    <div style="height: 100vh; margin-top: 20px;">Content to jump past</div>
    
    <div id="tableImagesSliding" style="height: 100vh;">
      Table plans
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the same thing and when I click the text, always go to home page. What could be wrong?

Comment: @batuman answer updated with Angular's `$anchorScroll` service

Answer (score 1):

If by call you mean scoll to the position of the div, the answer would be

```
<a href="#tableImagesSliding"> </a>
```

Comment: I did the same thing and when I click the text, always go to home page. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to add both a _name_ and an _id_ attribute too to the target div? I mean s.g. like this: `<div id="tableImagesSliding" name="tableImagesSliding">`